# MySql what's the best way to insert bookings

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database that looks like this

[image]

I was wondering with the separate tables and such, 
do i insert everything one table at a time,
Like insert a row in booking, insert a row in the Customers, and last insert a row in Booking_has_Customers?
Is there an easier way to do this?

Halls is unchanging just in case they have more rooms to hire.

And when retrieving data from the database, is it best to use a join on the foreign keys to get a full overview incase i need all data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No there is no easier way, you need to insert the data to each table individually. However, this is the exact situation that asks for [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html). Transactions ensure that either all required insertions happen, or none of them.
2. This question is pretty broad and cannot be generally answered. If it makes sense to retrieve data from multiple tables, then joins could be a good answer and foreign keys are good starting points for a join condition. But a join condition may have contain expressions beyond the foreign keys. It all depends the actual use case.

I would rather ask specific questions for specific use cases for reports / queries in separate questions. This way you can get answers tailored to the exact question.

Comment: Yes transactions of course! I was just wondering how i had to do the 2 foreign keys in the many-many relation between booking and customers. Since they both are auto-increment